# Avoiding fat initialisers when using DI with Swift

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, protocols

I am attempting to understand `DI` in Swift.

I understand there are frameworks like `Swinject` etc that can help with `DI`  however I am keen to understand this myself and not use the magic of too many frameworks.

Take the below code *as an example*.

The initialiser of my `ProfileService` is only going to continue to grow and get fatter and fatter as this *pseudo* service expands and since projects contain more than one class, the same pattern will repeat many many times.

How can this be avoided? I am hoping to find a way to support easy maintenance, while still getting all the benefits of direct and simple code injection.

I was thinking perhaps using a `Protocol` and a `Struct` to contain the dependencies and inject this in, however cannot understand how best to implement this.

```
import UIKit

class UserService {
    func currentUser() -> String {
        return "some username"
    }
}

class AvatarService {
    func currentUserAvatarUrl() -> String {
        return "https://foo.bar/image.png"
    }
}

class MessageService {
    func currentInbox() -> [String:String] {
        return [
            "9279n1n2283":"something something",
            "m2j292i2m2n":"something something something"
        ]
    }
}

class ProfileService {
    private let userService: UserService
    private let avatarService: AvatarService
    private let messageService: MessageService

    init(userService: UserService, avatarService: AvatarService, messageService: MessageService) {
        self.userService = userService
        self.avatarService = avatarService
        self.messageService = messageService
    }

    func getLoggedInUser() -> String {
        return userService.currentUser()
    }

    func getUserAvatar() -> String {
        return avatarService.currentUserAvatarUrl()
    }

    func getInboxMessages() -> [String:String] {
        return messageService.currentInbox()
    }
}

let userService = UserService()
let avatarService = AvatarService()
let messageService = MessageService()

let profileService = ProfileService(userService: userService, avatarService: avatarService, messageService: messageService)

profileService.getLoggedInUser()
profileService.getUserAvatar()
profileService.getInboxMessages()
```

Comment: What about using default values in your initializers? This will allow you to inject for testing purposes but still allow you to keep your initializers thin. See the dependency injection section here: https://medium.com/p/e1bc821cc4c3#da1d

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to not do dependency injection on these classes directly, at all. I would do something like this:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: Protocols

protocol UserService {
    var username: String { get }
}

protocol AvatarService {
    var userAvatarURL: URL { get }
}

protocol MessageService {
    var inbox: [String: String] { get }
}

protocol GlobalServiceContext {
    var userService: UserService { get }
    var avatarService: AvatarService { get }
    var messageService: MessageService { get }
}

// MARK: Mock Implementations

class MockUserService: UserService {
    let username = "test_user"
}

class MockAvatarService: AvatarService {
    let userAvatarURL = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png")!
}

class MockMessageService: MessageService {
    let inbox = [
        "test subject 1": "test message 1",
        "test subject 2": "test message 2",
        "test subject 3": "test message 3",
    ]
}

class MockServiceContext: GlobalServiceContext {
    let userService: UserService = MockUserService()
    let avatarService: AvatarService = MockAvatarService()
    let messageService: MessageService = MockMessageService()
}

// MARK: Mock Implementations

class ProdUserService: UserService {
    // TODO: Substitute real implementation here
    let username = "prod_user"
}

class ProdAvatarService: AvatarService {
    // TODO: Substitute real implementation here
    let userAvatarURL = URL(string: "https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki.png")!
}

class ProdMessageService: MessageService {
    let inbox = [ // TODO: Substitute real implementation here
        "Prod subject 1": "Prod message 1",
        "Prod subject 2": "Prod message 2",
        "Prod subject 3": "Prod message 3",
    ]
}

class ProdServiceContext: GlobalServiceContext {
    let userService: UserService = ProdUserService()
    let avatarService: AvatarService = ProdAvatarService()
    let messageService: MessageService  = ProdMessageService()
}

// MARK: Usage

let ServiceContext: GlobalServiceContext = MockServiceContext()

class ProfileService {
    var username: String { return ServiceContext.userService.username }
    var userAvatarURL: URL { return ServiceContext.avatarService.userAvatarURL }
    var inbox: [String:String] { return ServiceContext.messageService.inbox }
}

let profileService = ProfileService()
print(profileService.username)
print(profileService.userAvatarURL)
print(profileService.inbox)
```

It contains all your global state (your APIs, services, databases, etc.):

- into a single object
- that's available globally
- whose value can be substituted for a mock implementation

Answer (score 0):

Fat initializer when you are using DI, can be the sign of bad design and show that your component is not simple task. So you should try to break and decouple it.

Comment: For an effective answer, you would need to add way more detail. It's clear what you're suggesting should be done instead.